# compare arrays : one array is contained in the second array (key+value)

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

i want to check if one array is contained in the second array ,
but the same key and the same values,

(not need to be equal, only check that all **the key and value** in one array is in the second)

the simple thing that i do until now is :

```
function checkSameValues($a, $b){

        foreach($a as $k1 => $v1){                                  
            if($v1 && $v1 != $b[$k1]){
                return false;
                break;                                      
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Is there a simpler(faster) way to check this ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "blue", "c" => "white", "d" => "red");
$array2 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "blue", "d" => "red");
$result = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);
if (!count($result)) echo "array2 is contained in array";
```

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
$intersect = array_intersect_assoc($a, $b);
if( count($intersect) == count($b) ){
    echo "yes, it's inside";
}
else{
    echo "no, it's not.";
}
```

> > [**`array_intersect_assoc`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) 
> >     array_intersect_assoc() returns an array containing all the values of array1  that are present in all the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkSameValues($a, $b){
   if ( in_array($a,$b) ) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Comment: i need to check the same key and the same value , in_array check only values!

Answer (score 0):

This obviously only checks depth=1, but could easily be adapted to be recursive:

```
// check if $a2 is contained in $a1
function checkSameValues($a1, $a2)
{
    foreach($a1 as $element)
    {
        if($element == $a2) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$a1 = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'baz');
$a2 = array('el' => 'one', 'another' => $a1);

var_dump(checkSameValues($a2, $a1)); // true
```